# WPF image inside border is not fully drawn

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have an image within a border:

XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="TestProgram.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="Test" Height="350" Width="525">
<DockPanel>
    <Grid DockPanel.Dock="Top">
        <!---->
    </Grid>

    <ListBox DockPanel.Dock="Left"/>

    <Grid DockPanel.Dock="Top">
        <!---->
    </Grid>


    <Border x:Name="testBorder" ClipToBounds="True" Background="Gray">
        <Image x:Name="testImage" Source="test.png" Opacity="1" Stretch="None"
               MouseLeftButtonDown="testImage_MouseLeftButtonDown"
               MouseLeftButtonUp="testImage_MouseLeftButtonUp"
               MouseMove="testImage_MouseMove"
               />
    </Border>

</DockPanel>
</Window>
```

C#:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace TestProgram
{
/// <summary>
/// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
/// </summary>
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    private Point start;
    private Point origin;

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        TransformGroup group = new TransformGroup();

        TranslateTransform tt = new TranslateTransform();
        group.Children.Add(tt);

        testImage.RenderTransform = group;
    }

    private void testImage_MouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        testImage.CaptureMouse();
        TranslateTransform tt = (TranslateTransform)((TransformGroup)testImage.RenderTransform).Children.First(tr => tr is TranslateTransform);
        start = e.GetPosition(testBorder);
        origin = new Point(tt.X, tt.Y);
    }

    private void testImage_MouseLeftButtonUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        testImage.ReleaseMouseCapture();
    }

    private void testImage_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (testImage.IsMouseCaptured)
        {
            TranslateTransform tt = (TranslateTransform)((TransformGroup)testImage.RenderTransform).Children.First(tr => tr is TranslateTransform);
            Vector v = start - e.GetPosition(testBorder);
            tt.X = origin.X - v.X;
            tt.Y = origin.Y - v.Y;
        }
    }
}
}
```

I have added click & drag panning functionality, but the displayed size of the image is limited by the surrounding border, leaving only the top left corner of the image visible when the image is panned. This is the case even when i remove `ClipToBounds="True"`

`ActualHeight` and `ActualWidth` have values corresponding to the image's natural height and width, so why is the image clipped? What can I do to make the full image visible?

Comment: UI elements in WPF are constrained to the space allotted to them by their parent element.  In what kind of layout container is the `Border` placed?

Comment: The `Border` is inside a `DockPanel`

Comment: <ViewBox><Image x:Name="testImage" Source="test.png" Opacity="1" Stretch="None"/><ViewBox> or set the Width/Height of the Image.

Comment: Try placing border and image inside canvas

Comment: Give us full XAML with outer elements included...

Comment: @DeanK. added full XAML

Comment: Is using a ScrollViewer not possible? And can you make a small sample that reproduces the problem without having to drag the image?

Comment: @KendallFrey I added the code behind, although it does use dragging. `ScrollViewer` would work, thanks, but I'd still like to know how to avoid the clipping behavior with `Border`

Comment: Maybe the problem is you're using the wrong transform. Have you tried LayoutTransform? What happens?

Comment: @KendallFrey click and drag does not work at all with `LayoutTransform`

Comment: @Sajeetharan I think you should add that as an answer. I tried it out and I believe that is exactly what the OP is looking for (i.e. just change DockPanel to a Canvas).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really want the border to overlay on top of the the image, then put them both in a <`Grid`> or <`Canvas`>

```
 <Canvas>
   <Image/>
   <Borde/>
</Canvas>
```

Comment: The `Border` is only there as a container, but `<Canvas><Image /></Canvas>` has the functionality I need, thanks.